# Indie author, asking for book reviews

Tags: discussion

Is it OK to post something like "*I recently published a math book, now I am running a promotion campaign, you can dowload the book for free. I will appreciate any comments on the book, etc., etc.*" as a question on the MathUnderflow?

Comment: MathUnderflow is not used anymore since a long time (I am not even sure it was ever used much, in a non-pejorative sense).

Comment: Sorry, old habits die hard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question would not only be off-topic, it would arguably qualify as spam. Please do not post this type of content.

Of course, if in the process of writing a book an honest mathematical question arises, feel free to ask it. There is also nothing wrong with  mentioning your book-project as context in this case.

Yet, the motivation for posting a question should be an actual mathematical questions not the desire to promote your work.

The same goes for answers. It is alright to mentions ones own work in an answer, as long as it is actually pertinent information and this arises organically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I kept in mind was not promotion per se, but rather comments on the content, e.g. is the approach by the author to treat objects X reasonable/complicated/*; how certain proofs can improved/simplified/*, and so on. There is enough mathematics in that.

Comment: Such a question could be fine if it is narrow enough. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/25798/inviting-people-to-proofread-a-mathematical-text-allowed and the posts linked there.